# Can you select an element with two classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I have an element that has two classes but can't seem to select it with jQuery.
Is it possible.
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="abc/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($(".x.y").html()); //shows null, I want it to show "456"
      });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="x" class"y">456</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having two `class` attributes isn't valid SGML (therefore HTML), as far as I'm aware. Try this:

```
<div class="x y">456</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to target dual classes like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(".x.y").html()); //shows null, I want it to show "456"
});
```

with html like this:

```
<div class="x y">456</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This

```
<div class="x" class"y">456</div>
```

is incorrect, change it to

```
<div class="x y">456</div>
```